# Picasso not loading image from Samsung galaxy devices

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

On Nexus and LG G3 devices (which I have tried so far) I am successfully loading an image from the device memory into an ImageView (using Picasso) like this:

```
mProfileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 2);
    }
});


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        Picasso.with(getContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true);
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(data.getData())
                    .noPlaceholder()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .fit()
                    .into(mProfileImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

However, from some strange reason, this does not work on Galaxy S4 and S5.

I am using Picasso 2.5.2

Can any kind soul help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you select a very large image? try with small images. Also make sure you are using latest version of Picasso.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I am trying with 19KB JPEG with no luck

Comment: Do you receive any error on debugger?

Comment: The logger shows me this message twice: `E/MiniThumbFile: Unable to create .thumbnails directory /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails`

Comment: So basically on the Samsung device the data.getData() is returning null? Do a null check to narrow it down (if null then has nothing to do with Picasso).  Have you tried clearing your MediaStore and rebooting the phone?  Have you tried the method here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: @AliSheikhpour  The method that is used here only returns the Thumbnail in the data Intent

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I stated in my answer, it was a permission's problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NunoCosta  curious how it was working on any devices in the first place if it was a storage permission!

Comment: I think it's because the Galaxy was storing the images in the external memory and the other devices were storing in the internal memory. I didn't say it was working in any other devices though. I listed the devices that were working which I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *finally* figured it out!

It was a permission problem as the Samsung devices used external memory. After adding the following line to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It worked!